# Selecting multiple columns with linq query and lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I'm new to C# ASP.NET, and am working on my first application.

I'm trying to create a linq statment that return an arrary.

I have a table of products. I want to be able to select name, id, and price, for each product where the status == 1.

I am struggling with crating a way to do this.
I have only been able to return individual items/columns. I have been stuck on this wayyy to long.

This is what I have so far:

```
try
{
  using (UserDataDataContext db = new UserDataDataContext())
  {
    return db.mrobProducts.Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
  }
}
```

If you look in the screen shot below, you can see I have 2 errors, 
Select = Type object can not be refered from it's usage
ToArray = cant resolve symbol to array

[image]

Comment: I could not manage to put a where clause in, it would create an error, no matter where or how I was able to add it,

Comment: `return a 2 dimensional arrary`??

Comment: @GrantWinney, I've updated the question, as I have been implmenting everyones answer, and am still having issues here,,,

Comment: Change `string[]` to `Tuple<int, string, string>`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not sure what you table structure is like but see below.

```
public NamePriceModel[] AllProducts()
{
    try
    {
        using (UserDataDataContext db = new UserDataDataContext())
        {
            return db.mrobProducts
                .Where(x => x.Status == 1)
                .Select(x => new NamePriceModel { 
                    Name = x.Name, 
                    Id = x.Id, 
                    Price = x.Price
                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                .ToArray();
         }
     }
     catch
     {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

This would return an array of type anonymous with the members you require.

**Update:**

Create a new class.

```
public class NamePriceModel 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal? Price {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

I've modified the query above to return this as well and you should change your method from returning `string[]` to returning `NamePriceModel[]`.

Comment: The return get's an error, that says: Cant convert expression type Namstring, Pricestring to return type string[]

Comment: @Mark i'm not sure you have the right return type for the solution you are seeking. You might consider returning dynamic if you aren't interested in creating a type for it. A type would provide more clarity though.

Comment: @scaretag, would you be able to provide an example of this based on my updated question?

Comment: @Mark i've done that already. i've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: `OrderBy(x => x)` will not work, if the class doesn't implement `IComparable<T>` interface in the `NamePriceModel` class. Or OP have to order by some column.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Thanks .. i've edited it to order by Id. Although I suspect that the OP would have made that change already.

Comment: @scartag You will not beleive, but he asked a new question about this error. :)  [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231394/c-sharp-linq-query-keeps-hitting-catch)

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
public YourClass[] AllProducts()
{
    try
    {
        using (UserDataDataContext db = new UserDataDataContext())
        {
            return db.mrobProducts.Where(x => x.Status == 1)
                           .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
                           .Select(x => new YourClass { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name, Price = x.Price})
                           .ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is `YourClass` implementation:

```
public class YourClass
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public int Price {get; set;}
}
```

And your `AllProducts` method's return type must be `YourClass[]`.

Comment: thanks for the answer . worked for me.optimized query.

Answer (score 7):

using LINQ and Lamba, i wanted to return two field values and assign it to single entity object field;

as Name = Fname + " " + LName;

See my below code which is working as expected; hope this is useful;

```
Myentity objMyEntity = new Myentity
{
id = obj.Id,
Name = contxt.Vendors.Where(v => v.PQS_ID == obj.Id).Select(v=> new { contact = v.Fname + " " + v.LName}).Single().contact
}
```

no need to declare the 'contact'

Answer (score 2):

```
        Object AccountObject = _dbContext.Accounts
                                   .Join(_dbContext.Users, acc => acc.AccountId, usr => usr.AccountId, (acc, usr) => new { acc, usr })
                                   .Where(x => x.usr.EmailAddress == key1)
                                   .Where(x => x.usr.Hash == key2)
                                   .Select(x => new { AccountId = x.acc.AccountId, Name = x.acc.Name })
                                   .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: could you please Elaborate a Little on your proposed Code?

Comment: Here Accounts and User tables are connected by AccountId foreign key. where condition applied on user table columns .We are selecting two  columns from Accounts Table