# c# - Linq Query - Keeps hitting catch

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new to c#, so hopefully I can give you enough information here.

I am trying to return a list of products, where the product status column has a value of 1.

But, I keep hitting a my catch, and returning null.

I would like to create a list for each product, but I have not even got that far yet, currently just dumping the results into a viewdata.

The exception I am getting on the catach is:
*Invalid operation...:Cannot order by type 'Davey.Models.GetAllProducts'.*

Here is my code:

My Model: (Product Model)

```
namespace Davey.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class GetAllProducts 
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Price { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Points { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Cat { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SizeS { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SizeM { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SizeL { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SizeXL { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Service (DaveyService.scs): // This is where I keep hitting the catch block

```
public GetAllProducts[] AllProducts(int status)
{
    try
    {
        using (UserDataDataContext db = new UserDataDataContext())
        {
            return db.mrobProducts.Where(x => x.Status == status).Select(x => new               GetAllProducts { Name = x.Name, Desc = x.Description, Price = x.Price }).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And my controller, which has been cut down to the relevant part:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult UserLogin(LoginModel model, UserName usernameModel, GetAllProducts allProductsModel)
{
    if (userExists)
    {                   
        var webService3 = new DaveyServiceClient();
        allProductsModel.Status = 1;
        ViewData["products"] = webService.AllProducts(allProductsModel.Status);
        return View("../Private/Index");
    }       
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: If we know the exception...

Comment: Remove the `try..catch` block and tell us what the exception is.

Comment: Invalid Operation...:Cannot order by type 'Davey.Models.GetAllProducts'.

Comment: Also, don't catch without an exception type. At least catch(Exception e).

Comment: Also, why you have created `GetAllProducts`? You can just use `Select(x=>x)` if you need all columns values.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: Actually, you can remove the whole `Select`.

Comment: @recursive Yes, wrote this consciously to not confuse the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `OrderBy` method doesn't know how to sort by `GetAllProducers`.

You have two choices:

1. Implement `IComparable<GetAllProducts>` in `GetAllProducts`
2. Sort by something `OrderBy` will know how to sort by, like a `string` or an `int`, for example:

   ```
   using (UserDataDataContext db = new UserDataDataContext())
   {
        return db.mrobProducts.Where(x => x.Status == status).Select(x => new GetAllProducts 
              { 
                 Name = x.Name, 
                 Desc = x.Description, 
                 Price = x.Price 
              }).OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToArray();
    }
   ```

As a side note, i usually like to specify what im catching in my `catch` clause, as you should always do something with the exception you catch, even if its just logging. I suggest you use a specific type like `catch (InvalidOperationException e)` or if you really need a general catch then `catch (Exception e)`

Comment: I use bare `catch` regularly, and have never heard of a problem with it.

Comment: @recursive Well, using bare `catch` clauses had previous problems prior to .NET 2.0 with unmanaged exceptions not being translated properly. I usually always specify what should be caught. When you catch an exception, you should at least do something with it, if you dont, dont use a `catch` clause and let it propogate. I edited my answer to make it clear

Comment: Importing the `System.Linq` namespace also had problems prior to .NET 2.0, but no one's claiming you shouldn't do that.  Avoiding bare catches seems like superstition to me.  Rarely, you need to catch an exception, and not do anything with it.  For example, you're writing a unit test framework method that asserts that an `Action` throws an exception when invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the exception because you're ordering by a complex type. Do `...OrderBy(x=>x.Name)`, or by any other field you want to sort by.